# AsyncTask does not correctly restart in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am developing an Android application and I need show remind dialog from time to time in according to variable from shared preferences. If user does not want to see reminder message, he can disable this option also in my PreferenceActivity. I am using AsyncTask class to show remind message to user from time to time . User can press options button at every moment  to go to PreferenceActivity to enable/disable reminder option and set pause time value between reminds, and the go back to activity. So I am checking all values in onResume method. And if users does not want to see remind messages I need to finish current working AsyncTask, or if user changed value between reminds, I need to restart current AsyncTack with new pause value. But I see an unpredictable behavior of my AsyncTack: sometimes it stops, sometimes not and continue working and showing message)))), sometimes it works and sometimes - not))))).   Here is a piece of code:

This is my AsyncTack class

```
private class ReadReminderTask extends AsyncTask<Long, Void, Void> {
     private long mRemindTime;
     private volatile boolean running = true;
     public ReadReminderTask(){

     }
     @Override
     public Void doInBackground(Long... params){
         mRemindTime = params[0];
         while (running){
             try{
                 Thread.sleep(mRemindTime);
                 publishProgress();
             }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
         return null;
     }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        // showReminder is a method where I show remind message
        showReminder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        running = false;
    }
 }
```

This is onResume method of my Activity where I need to show reminder message:

```
if(!settings.getBoolean("needToRemind", false)) {
        mReadReminderTask.cancel(true);
    } else if(settings.getBoolean("needToRemind", false)) {
        mReadReminderTask = new ReadReminderTask();
        mReadReminderTask.execute(settings.getLong("timeRemind", 1));
    }
```

Can anyone help me with my problem?

Comment: In your else if statement you're creating a new task and executing it, I don't think that will stop the old task. Try to cancel the task, then check if it's cancelled, if it is, start the same task with different parameters, else try to cancel it again and check. don't create a new task each time.

Comment: Three out of three solutions here are telling you *not* to "try this".  Really, dude: you are doin it wrong.

Comment: Okay, but I'm so confused in dealing with this problem, so I am trying all solutions)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's really not such a great way to do that.  The "unpredictable behavior" happens because you leave the task running even after your `Activity` is stopped.  The call to `cancel` in your `onResume` is not only too late, it actually is not doing anything at all.

Have a look at `Handler.postDelayed`.  You want something like this:

In your `onCreate`

```
hdlr = new Handler();
reminder = new Runnable() { public void run() { showReminder(); } }
```

**EDITED TO ADD ESSENTIAL 2ND PARAM TO postDelayed**

... in your `onResume`:

```
hdlr.postDelayed(reminder, mRemindTime);
```

... and, in your `onPause`:

```
hdlr.removeCallbacks(reminder);
```

Comment: And in  run() method i need to make something like Thread.SLeep(val) before initReminder()? Am i right?

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works for me. I only added hdlr.postDelayed(reminder, time); into run() method after showReminder(); call.

Comment: @bukka.wh  Yes!  Thanks for pointing out that my code missed that essential parameter.  Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that AsyncTask.cancel() does not really cancel running task. Instead it only sets a flag to notify that cancel has been requested. It is up to AsyncTask implementation if and when to take this flag into account.

Your current code does not check for cancellation after Thread.sleep returns. Correct implementation would be something like:

```
public Void doInBackground(Long... params){
     mRemindTime = params[0];
     while (!isCancelled()){
         try{
             Thread.sleep(mRemindTime);
             if(!isCancelled())
                 publishProgress();
         }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
     return null;
 }
```

Also attribute 'running' and onCancelled() method in your asynctask are not needed. You can use method 'isCancelled()' instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a bad solution. `AsyncTasks` are not great in handling config changes.

Depending on how long the delays are, you can use `AlarmManager.setInexactRepeating` in order to show these dialogs. You can create new `PendingIntent` using `PendingIntent.getService` or `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` depending on how you'd like to implement showing dialog – (from `Service` you will be able to show only system-like dialogs).

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intentStart = new Intent();
intentStart.setAction(SHOW_DIALOG_ACTION);
PendingIntent pendingIntentStart = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentStart, 0);
```

And register a BroadcastReceiver which will handle showing the dialog.

If the delays are not long, you can create a custom `ThreadPoolExecutor` which will do what you want.

Comment: Alarm manager is a great, if heavy-weight, solution.  AsyncTasks are, exactly, tasks run on a ThreadPoolExecutor.  Re-implementing AsyncTasks with a custom ThreadPoolExecutor is *not* a great solution.

Comment: @G. Blake Meike
Yes, you are right. But you have a little bit more control about what's going on.

I can also suppose using `Handler` with `postDelayed` posting the same `Runnable`, though I am not sure how it'll handle config changes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think AsyncTask should be used for that. `Thread.sleep(mRemindTime)` is also very ugly! If you need a timer use [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html).

Comment: Can CountDownTime do some work all with some interval all time while my Activity is running?

Comment: Do you mean this `onTick(long millisUntilFinished)`?